# sbopkg is not working with proxy

Tags: rsync, proxy, slackware, slackbuilds

Sbopkg used to work on my computer untill the network admin started to make a compulsory for the user to use proxy before connecting to the Internet. So, when I tried to sync to slackbuilds, I'm getting these errors:

```
root@meh:~# sbopkg -r
Syncing with the remote repository into /var/lib/sbopkg/SBo/13.1.
rsync: failed to connect to slackbuilds.org: Connection timed out (110)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(122) [Receiver=3.0.7]

Rsync reported a socket error which may be due to
a problem with the LINK value in sbopkg.conf.
(The repo's LINK is currently set to: slackbuilds.org::slackbuilds/13.1).
Please check your settings and try again later.
```

Comment: have you told sbopkg to use the proxy yet? looks like it is trying to communicate directly.

Comment: I've tried exporting http_proxy and I believe the http_proxy setting is working since I can use wget but I think sbopkg uses rsync.

Comment: Hello @amree could you vote on the proposal to add a Slackware site here on SE: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74486/slackware?referrer=dhvXUXM_aZkT61QvCK6PSg2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rsync docs suggest:

> You may establish the connection via a web proxy by setting the environment variable 
>   RSYNC_PROXY to a hostname:port pair pointing to your web proxy. Note that your web proxy's 
>   configuration must allow proxying to port 873.

Have you tried that?

Comment: tried exporting rsync_proxy=http://someproxy:someport and I'm still getting the same error, how do I check if my network allow 873 port?

Comment: Note that environment variables are usually case-sensitive, so rsync_proxy is not the same as RSYNC_PROXY. To see if it works, I'd try connecting to a public rsync URL with rsync. Strictly for testing, try this: mkdir test ; rsync -avzH --delete msync.centos.org::CentOS test

Comment: Just tried and I got "bad response from proxy -- HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden". I guess it's blocked, thanks for the guide.